# Replace marker in clustermanager, GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps in my android project. I create my own ClusterMarkerLocation implements ClusterItem and now because I get LatLng dynamically from a web service if I get 2nd-time same LatLng I want to overwrite it because I want to have another title in marker. So, I try to delete like :

clusterManager.removeItem(temp);

temp is ClusterMarkerLocation type and then I call

clusterManager.cluster();

And it doesn't delete marker but add 2 markers in same x,y and make clustering.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove all old markers to add new one

Identify global variable and make it Instance from googleMap when onMapReady() called as the code below

```html
    private GoogleMap mMap; 
  //start showing map
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        this.mMap = googleMap;

    }
```

After that you can use mMap to delete all marker as you want by using the following method

```
  mMap.clear();
```

After that you can add the new marker by using

```
 mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

Comment: No this solution clear my map, i want to keep my marker but if i have 2nd with same LatLng to overwrite. Anyway thanks for answer